How to determine statistical significance for a time series and forecasts?
With a simple example of mortality rates, and a basic three-year mean baseline:
df <- tibble(
  year = 2017:2022,
  actual = c(904, 889, 839, 913, 835, 836)
)
df$forecast <- rep(mean(df$actual), 6)
df$diff <- df$actual - df$forecast
df
# A tibble: 6 × 4
#    year actual forecast  diff
#   <int>  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  2017    904     869.  34.7
# 2  2018    889     869.  19.7
# 3  2019    839     869. -30.3
# 4  2020    913     869.  43.7
# 5  2021    835     869. -34.3
# 6  2022    836     869. -33.3

What would be the correct approach to determine, if values 2020:2022 by themselves, and cumulatively represent a stat. sign. change from the previous observed values (i.e. the forecasts)?

It depends: do you know the standard errors of the forecasts?

Yes, i can either calculate them or use fable::TSLM model to do that...

I think I can get the std errors like this:
ts <- df |> as_tsibble(index = year) model <- ts |> model(TSLM(actual)) fc <- model |> forecast(h = 3) fc |> mutate(   .var = distributional::variance(actual),   .stderr = sqrt(.var) )
